# SwiftLint failing while file path have space

Tags: swiftlint

some of the file in my project are grouped with folder name with space. I added SwiftLint in my project and while any changes in file with space in file path SwiftLint gives exception. please help me.

SwiftLint version : 0.46.2

error:

```
error opening input file '/Users/mg/Documents/Project/Folder/CustomeCell/SwiftCode.swift' (No such file or directory)
Most rules will be skipped because sourcekitd has failed.
SourceKittenFramework/File.swift:20: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “paymentOptionCell.swift” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/mg/Documents/Project/Folder/CustomeCell/SwiftCode.swift, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002ad8000 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

actual path: `/Users/mg/Documents/Project/My\ Module\ Folder/CustomeCell/SwiftCode.swift`

Comment: I just make sure I never have any spaces in the files or folders that belongs to my projects. It makes things so much easier in many respects, not only when using swiftlint.

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: @mastermind I did not found any solution so i removed space from path and it started working